# How to apply constructor injectivity in the goal

Tags: coq, inductive-type, backward-proof

Suppose I have a goal

```ml
Goal forall m n, S m = S n -> m = n.
  intros m n H.

1 goal
  
  m, n : nat
  H : S m = S n
  ============================
  m = n
```

I know that I can use `injection H as H` to transform `H` to `m = n`.
However, sometimes I would like to transform the goal instead.
In the specific case of `nat`, there is the lemma `eq_add_S`:

```ml
Goal forall m n, S m = S n -> m = n.
  intros m n H.
  apply eq_add_S.

1 goal
  
  m, n : nat
  H : S m = S n
  ============================
  S m = S n
```

However, is there a tactic like `injection` that will work for any constructor?

Comment: But `injection H` (without `as`) just changes the goal, leaving the context unchanged. Then you can  use `intro`, `rewrite`, `subst`, etc.,  to resume your proof.

Comment: It is a bit of a mouthful, but you can do `enough (S m = S n) by congruence.`. What should be the behaviour of the tactic you envision? In particular, what if the inductive type has two constructors (think `nat` with an extra `S' : nat -> nat`), what goal should the tactic generate in your setting? `S m = S n`? `S' m = S' n`? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an ad-hoc tactic

```ml
Ltac injection_goal v := 
match goal with 
|- ?A = ?B => 
  let H := fresh "H" in assert (H: v A = v B); try now injection H 
end.

Goal forall m n,  S m = S n -> m = n.
intros m n H.
injection_goal S.
```